# System of linear equations with complex parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

This system has to be solved depending on (in relation to) the value of the complex parameters **p** and **q**

$$x_1  +x_2  +x_3  +x_4  = -1$$
$$x_1  -x_2  +x_3  -x_4  =  1$$
$$x_1  +x_2  -x_3  +x_4  =  1$$
$$x_1  -x_2  +px_3 +qx_4 =  2$$

I would like to show some work I've done but I'm stuck how to start because I don't think I understand properly the problem. I would like someone to explain how these type of problems are approached, are there steps I could follow when solving? I couldn't find similar problems for reference.

Comment: I think you're being asked to find formulas for $x_1,\dots,x_4$ that satisfy the equations, where the formulas are allowed to have $p$ and $q$ in them. If you know how to solve an ordinary system of four equations in four unknowns, then you know how to solve this problem, too – you just treat $p$ and $q$ as numbers as you do the calculations. Try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & p & q \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
For Cramer's rule the system has one unique solution is and only if $\det A\ne 0\to =4+4q\ne0 \to q\ne-1$

Thanks to [Rouché–Capelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem)

If $q=-1$ then $\text{rank}(A)=3$. the system has solution only if $\text{rank}(A|B)=\text{rank}(A)=3$.

This happens if all the $4$th order determinants of $A|B$ are zero, in particulat if
$$\det\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & p & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right|=4p=0\to p=0$$
The system has infinite solution if $q=-1$ and $p=0$.

From the augmented matrix
$$A|B=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
we choose a order $3$ submatrix with nonzero determinant, for instance
$$A'=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and solve
$$\begin{cases}
x_1  +x_2  +x_3    = -1-x_4\\
x_1  -x_2  +x_3    =  1+x_4\\
x_1  +x_2  -x_3    =  1-x_4\\
\end{cases}
$$
which gives
$$x_1= 1,x_2= -x_4-1,x_3= -1$$